# jQuery click event not redirecting to href

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, nyromodal, preventdefault

I've got an HTML page with an embedded flash movie, which has a button. This button in flash invokes the lnkEmail's click event. It's supposed to stop from actually navigating to a new page, but the event.preventDefault(); and the returning of false from the event handler don't seem to be working for me. Can anyone provide insight?

The below example is working in Chrome, but fails in IE 7 and FF. In those browsers it redirects to a blank page with Object [object] as the body and in FF has the url set to the javascript code I execute from within the Flash movie. (ie: "javascript:jQuery('#lnkEmail').click();")

Below is the code in the Flash ActionScript.

```
cmdDemo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
   navigateToURL(
      new URLRequest(
         "javascript:jQuery('#lnkEmail').click();"
      ), 
      "_self"
   );
}
```

In the containing HTML page there is the following scripts and elements:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
      $.nyroModalSettings({
         debug: true
      });

      $('#lnkEmail').click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $.nyroModalManual({
            url: 'demoRequest.aspx?Type=4'
         });
         return false;
      });
   });
</script>
```

And later in the same file:

```
<div id="box_stage_home">
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() { 
         $('#HomeAnimation').flash({ 
            swf: 'Flash/index_page.swf', 
            height: 288, 
            width: 686, 
            wmode: 'transparent' 
         }); 
      });
   </script>
   <div id="HomeAnimation"><!--IE 6.0--></div>
   <a href="emailSend.aspx?Type=4" id="lnkEmail">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that this works in Chrome. But in IE 7 and in FF it redirects to a page with Object [object] and a url as javascript:jQuery('#lnkEmail').click();.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can edit your original post by clicking  the `edit` link in the lower right-hand corner of the question - no need to comment for something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the proper way (thanks corneliu) to do this so thought I'd post it back on here for reference. In the html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function viewDemo() {
      $.nyroModalManual({
         url: 'emailSend.aspx?Type=4'
      });           
   }
</script>
```

In the flash file:

```
import flash.system.Security;

cmdDemo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
   flash.system.Security.allowDomain("business.com");
   ExternalInterface.call("viewDemo");
}
```

Comment: Awesome, hey Rob you should be able to accept your own answer. That will help anyone else who may find this by search.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `navigateToURL` documentation: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29. It is not intendend to be used with `javascript:` links.

To do what you want, use `ExternalInterface.call()`.

Comment: Adding void(0); after the call to navigateToURL() ended up being the solution. The void(0); tells the browser not to open a new page specifically. Found this on a Flash documentation page somewhere, can't remember at the moment. Oh and yes had to add  allowScriptAccess="always" to the flash vars. I also see now how to use ExternalInterface to do it, which does indeed look like the proper way to do it.

Comment: Said that wrong before... Adding void(0); after the call to click() on the lnkEmail element, inside the javascript, ended up being the solution.

Comment: "javascript:jQuery('#lnkEmail').click(); void(0);"